# Inserting data from one table to another leads to duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table1 with columns ( id, id_user ) and table2 with columns (id, username).
The users are registered in table2. So what I want is to insert the `table2.id` of the new registered users in `table1.id_user`.

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id_user) SELECT id FROM table2;
```

but the result is:

for example I have in `table1.id`:

```
 id
 1
 2
 3
```

and when the new users register in table2 the `table1.id` looks like this:

```
id
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
```

and it repeats all the data every time there is a new registered user.
How can I fix this to only add the newly registered user?

Comment: You could also put a Primary Key/Unique constraint on ID so that attempts at inserting the same value would result in a duplicate key constraint; thus fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1  (id_user) 
    SELECT id FROM table2 where id not in (select id_user from table1)
```

If you use a DB trigger then you could insert the new user id from table2 in table1 automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use `max` key word.its work in your case.

```
 " INSERT INTO table1  (id_user) SELECT max id FROM table2"
```

Comment: Only if there is only one new user.